# Limit of absolute value of a function

Tags: limits

is the following statement correct:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} |f(x)| = 1 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) \neq 0$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Provided the limit exists ! Counterexample: $f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. It is correct if you interpret the statement
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \neq 0$$
as "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$ either does not exist, or if it does exist, then it is not equal to $0$". I would personally avoid using $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$, unless it does exist.

How do you prove it? Simple. Recall that $| \cdot |$ is continuous (indeed non-expansive) by the reverse triangle inequality. Thus, $f(x) \to 0 \implies |f(x)| \to |0| = 0$. Contrapositively, if the limit of $|f(x)|$ existed but was not $0$ (e.g. $1$), then it could not be that $f(x) \to 0$; either $f(x)$ has no limit, or the limit is not $0$.

Comment: thanks!the thing is that f(x) is a series. in that sense i am not sure if it could be thought of as continuous?

Comment: @17_prime It's not about $f(x)$ being continuous, but $| \cdot |$ being continuous. All we require of $f(x)$ is that it have a limit as $x \to \infty$. Then $|f(x)|$ will have to have a limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: For the first paragraph, wouldn't it be better to write, not($\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$) ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson That might be a little clearer than $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \neq 0$. I would still generally prefer writing it out in the full sentence, rather than use $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ when the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to\infty} |f(x)| = 1 \Rightarrow (\limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1) \ or \ (\liminf_{x\to\infty} f(x) = -1) \ (or \ both),$

which implies $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) \neq 0$

Comment: I would be cautious about stating that a limit can be both $1$ and $-1$ in your first line.  This would normally imply that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes you're right, being technically incorrect for the sake of providing intuition is a bad idea for trying to help someone who is probably relatively new to limits and convergence. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Now my brackets look iffy, so feel free to make my answer look better.

Comment: thanks @AdamRubinson for your answer. this is the series i am talking about: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -1^{n+1} 2^{n} / 2^{n} + 1$$

Comment: In the above, is the +1 a part of the summand, or outside the sum?

Comment: all inside the sum. i wanted to show the series is divergent because the limit of the f(x) is not equal to 0.

Comment: why don't the two 2^n 's cancel to 1?

Comment: this is the series with correct formatting: $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty -1^{n+1} \displaystyle \frac{n^2}{{n^2 + 1}} $$

Comment: Well, this is an entirely different question to the one originally asked, so I advise you to search for an answer on stackexchange via google, for which there will very likely be one, or if you can't find it, ask it as a new question.
The answer, by the way is, yes: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, which is the contrapositive of what you're looking for.